# Proper way to implement thread-safe method in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, c++11, mutex

I have a class representing different kind of tools (GCC, LEX, YACC, ...).
Each instance is given a type representing the tool, and permit special configuration.

To handle default configuration, I have a set of maps and vector storing defaults values. As I want that class to be usable in every context, it would have to be thread-safe, thus to avoid race I implemented the following:

```
int Tool::addType(std::string typeName,
        std::string typeFlagName)
    throw (GP::Exceptions::LockAcquisitionException)
{   
    static std::timed_mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::timed_mutex> lock{mutex};

    int typeId = 0;

    if (lock.try_lock_for(std::chrono::microseconds(100)))
    {   
        int typeId = typeNames.size();
        typeNames[typeId] = typeName;
        typeFlagNames[typeId] = typeFlagName;
    }   
    else
    {   
        throw GP::Exceptions::LockAcquisitionException{"Unable to generate new type ID within 100 microseconds."};
    }   
    return typeId;
}
```

I would like to know if this is a good solution or if I miss something.
If this is okay, is there another solution less verbose?

Comment: It will prevent two separate threads from adding types at the same time, but it *won't* prevent one thread from adding a type at the same time as another thread is trying to retrieve a type. That seems unsafe to me . . .

Comment: I agree with ruakh. You should just have a std::mutex member for the whole object and every member call. Then just use the simpler std::lock_guard instead of fooling around with a timed lock.

Comment: The types won't be altered, just one will be added. The read access won't cause a race condition.

Comment: It is still reading and writing concurrently to whatever structure you are using to store the types. If it is an STL container, then this is unsafe, because STL does not support concurrent reading and writing. And I bet an STL container because of the .size() call.

Comment: Yes it is an STL container. So how should I do this? Having an object-mutex will lock all methods of the same type

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Isn't timed_mutex better if I want to test access for 100 microseconds ?

Comment: Just one note: don't use exception specification. All it does is forcing an analysis of every exception that leaves your function at runtime and calling terminate should an exception leave that is not derived from the one specified... In C++11, there are `noexcept` methods and there are the others, `throw(...)` is effectively deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not something like?

```
class tool
{
    std::atomic<int> index_;
    std::array<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, 2048> types_; // Should be more than enough room.

    int addType(std::string typeName, std::string typeFlagName)
    {   
        int id = index++;

        if(id >= types_.size())
            throw GP::Exceptions{"To many types."};

        types_[id] = std::make_pair(typeName, typeFlagName);

        return id;
    }

};
```

You could make this a bit smarter by using std::vector and have a lock only when it needs to be reallocated for a larger size.

NOTE: the throw() clause is deprecated in C++11.

Comment: "You could make this a bit smarter by using std::vector and have a lock only when it needs to be reallocated for a larger size." - i dont see any way to do this without locking it before getting the size...

Comment: You mean the throw in the method declaration ? Thanks for your response, but I would really like to implement complete thread-safety, not using a workaround (although it may be better sometimes)

Comment: Yes I mean the throw in the declaration. And this IS complete thread-safety, what part exactly is no thread-safe and a workaround?

Comment: I meant using mutex & locks. Because I also have to implemented setters for which I can't do like that.

Comment: Could you please also describe your setters and getters in your question?

Comment: Yes, I though I will do something like that. But what If I delete a type? The index will continue to increment but it will break the array values. Perhaps I could use a int-indexed map or unordered_map ?
Or I let empty values in the array?

Comment: That depends on what "delete" a type means... and why/when you would do that.

Comment: I think you should provide more information about your Tool class, it seems you have a lot requirements outside of what you have described in your question, e.g. remove type, getters/setters etc... It is very difficult to give you a complete answer to an incomplete question.

Comment: There's much more to say about this class, but I think it will be too long to post here. BTW, this mean that std::atomic is thread-safe ?

Comment: sorry i misread part of the code, i thought you were adding a new element so a reallocation might occur.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be:

```
class tool
{ 
   std::mutex myMutex;

   std::vector<std::string> typeNames;   

   int addType(std::string typeName)
   {
       std::lock_guard myLock(myMutex);
       typeNames.push_back(typeName);
       return typeNames.size()-1; // 
   }

   // Only hold lock when needed
   void longComplexFunction(int f)
   {
       // Compute as much as possible before
       int complexMagic = veryLongFunction(f);

       {
          std::lock_guard myLock(myMutex);
          typeNames[complexMagic] += "s";
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: And what happends if lock_guard fails to get the lock?

Comment: It sleeps until the lock is available.

Comment: just a last question, what can I do for the getters? Is there something like boost::shared_mutex I can use alongside with std::lock_guard ?